# Clash between KOMA-Script and lmodern: how to fix the \implies bug?

Tags: koma-script, standalone, lmodern

I want to fix the "bug" of the `\implies` symbol, which is not rendered properly for large font sizes. Accordingly to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137514/8323), I used the `lmodern` package and redefined a symbol (see the answer).

But there is, seemingly, a clash between `KOMA-Script` and `modern` packages, as the MWE shows (the sign `\int` is not rendered at the right size):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\KOMAoptions{fontsize=20pt}

\begin{document}

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 f(t) dt \implies 1=1$

\end{document}
```

[image]

So, my question is: How to fix the "bug" of `\implies` so that it still works with the `scrreprt` package? The "bug" of `\implies` is the bumps you can see in the middle of the implies symbol.

---

Remark: I use the `KOMA-Script` package only to modify the font size in the `standalone` package, with

```
\documentclass[class=scrreprt]{standalone}
```

Comment: A minimal example: `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\Huge$\Longrightarrow$\end{document}`. The problem is unrelated to KOMA-Script and `lmodern`. `amsmath` `\Implies` uses `\Longrightarrow` as underlying symbol. The symbol is composed of `=` and `\Rightarrow`. They do not match too well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fix by egreg in the question you linked too works perfectly also with scrartcl. If you want a larger integral you can load the excale package (after lmodern!):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{exscale}
\KOMAoptions{fontsize=20pt}
\makeatletter
% Load the OT1 definitions for lmodern
\input{ot1lmr.fd}
% Change the definition for \OT1/lmr/m/n/<size>
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{lmr}{m}{n}%
  {<-5.5>    rm-lmr5  <5.5-6.5> rm-lmr6
   <6.5-7.5> rm-lmr7  <7.5-8.5> rm-lmr8
   <8.5-9.5> rm-lmr9  <9.5->    rm-lmr10
  }{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 f(t) dt \implies 1=1$

\end{document}
```

[image]