# Implies arrow looks off

Tags: formatting

So I've compiled my latex code and I found that the implies arrow looks slightly distorted
[image: Implies]

Is this normal, and is it possible for me to fix this?

EDIT: a snippet of my code below:

```
\documentclass[15pt]{article}

% define paper margins
\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    portrait,
    top=1.2cm,
    bottom=1.2cm,
    left=1.5cm,
    right=1.5cm,
    headheight=15pt, % avoid warning by fancyhdr
    includehead,includefoot,
    heightrounded % to avoid underfull messages
]{geometry} 

% Make justifications better.
\usepackage{microtype}

% Allows inclusion of sample text.
\usepackage{blindtext}

% Gets outlines right.
\usepackage{bookmark}

% ams stuff
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}

% Bold math for vectors and the lot.
\usepackage{bm}

% Allows inclusion of special spaces
\usepackage{xspace}

% fancy headers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% Allows inclusion of custom fonts.
\usepackage{fontspec}

% Allows the use of custom enumerators in lists.
\usepackage{enumitem}

% Allows drawing of graphical images.
\usepackage{tikz}

% Allows inclusion of images.
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Allows inclusion of links
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Allows boxes to be drawn around text and math environments.
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

% Includes extra mathtools.
\usepackage{mathtools}

% hyperref setup
\hypersetup {
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,
    urlcolor=cyan
}

% Paragraph indenting and skipping.
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

% Augmented Matrix environment.
\newenvironment{amatrix}[1]{%
  [\begin{array}{@{}*{#1}{c}|c@{}}
}{%
  \end{array}]
}

% Commands
\newcommand{\latex}{\LaTeX\xspace}

\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}
\newcommand{\reals}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\naturals}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\integers}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\rationals}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

% Fixing brackets
\let\originalleft\left
\let\originalright\right
\renewcommand{\left}{\mathopen{}\mathclose\bgroup\originalleft}
\renewcommand{\right}{\aftergroup\egroup\originalright}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Span}{Span}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}


% Font
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Roboto}

% Title
\title{test document}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \frac{c-b}{2} &= \prod_{q\in Q}q^2 & \frac{c+b}{2} &= \prod_{s\in S}s^2\\[1em]
    &= \left(\prod_{q\in Q}q\right)^2 & &= \left(\prod_{s\in S}s\right)^2\\[1em]
    &\implies \text{blah blah blah}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is *not* normal.  The basic two-line arrow is extended by attaching one or more = signs.  This requires use of compatible arrow and = glyphs.  In order to help, we need to know what document class and fonts are being used.  Please provide a small compilable example that begins with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` that produces this error.

Comment: Looks like [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137501/194703) is very much related.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Ok, I've included the code now

Comment: Sorry, I need to edit it again, I missed the bit where I used the implies symbol. It's in now.

Comment: Empirically when removing `\setmainfont{Roboto}` the issue seems to go away.

Comment: If you can use `unicode-math`, this is one of many bits of old technical debt that it clears away.

Comment: @Davislor Problem is, I don't know what unicode maths is. Is it vastly different to amsmath?

Comment: `unicode-math` sets up fonts using Unicode references.  It doesn't conflict with any of the `amsmath` equation structures.

Comment: @barbarabeeton oh, sounds great. So if I use that package, will the problem go away?

Comment: It’s a package that lets you load OpenType text and math fonts. [There’s a list of them here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available) You would load it instead of `amsfonts` and your other font packages. It’s backward-compatible with existing commands.

Comment: It should go away. You’d want to make a few tweaks (It obsoletes `bm`, `amsfonts` and other legacy 8-bit font packages, for example.)

Comment: So if I wanted to use bold maths and Roboto font (or some other sans-serif font), how would I configure my document header? @Davislor

Comment: Do you need bold symbols, or just letters like ***v***? And do you want to use sans-serif in math mode?

Comment: @Davislor yeah, I need bold symbols, but if there is a sans-serif maths mode font, then I am interested. Otherwise, I can stick to the computer modern maths font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s one set of answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137501/194703).  However, this is one of those pieces of decades-old technical debt that you can sweep away by using the modern toolchain.

Specifically, if you use the `unicode-math` package, and compile with LuaLaTeX, it will use the Unicode symbol for ⇒.  (I would recommend LuaLaTeX over XeLaTeX because it supports the font expansion feature of `microtype`.)

```
\documentclass[15pt]{article}

% define paper margins
\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    portrait,
    top=1.2cm,
    bottom=1.2cm,
    left=1.5cm,
    right=1.5cm,
    headheight=15pt, % avoid warning by fancyhdr
    includehead,includefoot,
    heightrounded % to avoid underfull messages
]{geometry} 

% Make justifications better.
\usepackage{microtype}

% Allows inclusion of sample text.
\usepackage{blindtext}

% Gets outlines right.
\usepackage{bookmark}

% ams stuff
\usepackage{amsthm}

% Allows inclusion of special spaces
\usepackage{xspace}

% fancy headers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% Allows the use of custom enumerators in lists.
\usepackage{enumitem}

% Allows drawing of graphical images.
\usepackage{tikz}

% Allows inclusion of images.
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Allows inclusion of links
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Allows boxes to be drawn around text and math environments.
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

% Includes extra mathtools.
\usepackage{mathtools}

% Use Unicode math fonts.
\usepackage{unicode-math}

% hyperref setup
\hypersetup {
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,
    urlcolor=cyan
}

% Paragraph indenting and skipping.
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

% Augmented Matrix environment.
\newenvironment{amatrix}[1]{%
  [\begin{array}{@{}*{#1}{c}|c@{}}
}{%
  \end{array}]
}

% Commands
\newcommand{\latex}{\LaTeX\xspace}

\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}
\newcommand{\reals}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\naturals}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\integers}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\rationals}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

% Fixing brackets
\let\originalleft\left
\let\originalright\right
\renewcommand{\left}{\mathopen{}\mathclose\bgroup\originalleft}
\renewcommand{\right}{\aftergroup\egroup\originalright}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Span}{Span}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}


% Font
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Roboto}[Scale=1.0]
\setmathfont{Fira Math}

% Title
\title{test document}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \frac{c-b}{2} &= \prod_{q\in Q}q^2 & \frac{c+b}{2} &= \prod_{s\in S}s^2\\[1em]
    &= \left(\prod_{q\in Q}q\right)^2 & &= \left(\prod_{s\in S}s\right)^2\\[1em]
    &\implies \text{blah blah blah}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Fira Math sample]

I chose Fira Math as the math font above.  As of 2020, it’s the only sans-serif OpenType math font.

That sample is nearly identical to your MWE, minus a few packages that are obsolete when using `unicode-math` (`bm`, `amssymb`) or already loaded by it (`amsmath`, `fontspec`).  I also removed the redundant `Mapping=` option from `fontspec`.

There is one change you would need to make to your source: if you had been using `\bm`, you would use `\mathbf` instead.  (Or `\mathbfup` for upright, `\mathbfit` for italic.)  You say in the comments that you want this for vectors.  If that’s all you need, you can stop reading here.

The `\boldsymbol` command still works, as does `\boldmath` and `\mathversion{bold}`.  These are the only way to get bold operators.  However, as of 2020, the only free math fonts that include a bold version are XITS Math and Libertinus Math.  If you load one of those, it will automatically enable `\boldsymbol`, but otherwise, you need to add a command such as

```
\setmathfont[version=bold]{Libertinus Math Bold}
```

In a pinch, you might even try,

```
\setmathfont[version=bold, FakeBold=1.2]{Fira Math}
```

But I don’t recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to give me amazing suggestions! Should I message you if I need any extra clarifications?

Comment: @Kookie Sure, but no guarantee of a timely response. By the way, there’s a package for the trick you did with `\parindent` and `\parskip`, `\usepackage{parskip}`.

Comment: Ok, I'll search up the documentation for that