# Implies glyph misaligned when using non-default font

Tags: fonts, symbols

I have similar problem as [There's a bump in the implies glyph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137501/theres-a-bump-in-the-implies-glyph). I have no issues with `\implies` when using default font:
[image]

But when using an non-default font I have a misaligned `\implies`:
[image]

A MWE is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{
    xeCJK,                   % Chinese for XeTex
    fontspec,                % customize font
}
\setmainfont{NotoSerif-Regular} % from noto-fonts arch package
\setsansfont{NotoSans-Regular} % from noto-fonts arch package, use in \textsf
\setmonofont{FiraCode-Regular} % from ttf-fira-code arch package, used in \texttt
\setCJKmainfont{SourceHanSansCN-Regular} % from adobe-source-han-sans arch package, for chinese and japanese
\begin{document}


A $\implies$ B

Above is using custom font

\end{document}
```

I use xelatex (`Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=xelatex)`).

By reading [There's a bump in the implies glyph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137501/theres-a-bump-in-the-implies-glyph) I realize that this is caused by `\implies` uses two different symbols. But are there ways to fix such problems for custom fonts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to use `notomath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{
    xeCJK,                   % Chinese for XeTex
    fontspec,                % customize font
}
\usepackage[scale=1.1156]{notomath}

\setmainfont{NotoSerif-Regular}
\setsansfont{NotoSans-Regular}
\setmonofont{FiraCode-Regular}
%\setCJKmainfont{SourceHanSansCN-Regular}

\begin{document}

$A \implies B$

Above is using custom font

\end{document}
```

[image]

I commented out the Chinese font, because I don't have it and it's irrelevant for the issue.

Comment: Perfect! This solved my problem!